# make: "no rule to make target '/aic7xxx_seq.h' needed by 'aic7xxx_core.o' when installing driver for SCSI Controller

Tags: linux, makefile

I'm working in an Ubuntu 18.04LTS environment and I am trying to connect an old SCSI controller to my workstation.

The Card is a AHA_2940AU PCI to SCSI controller from Adapatec.  I got the driver source code from Adaptec's website at this link: https://storage.microsemi.com/en-us/speed/scsi/linux/aic7yxx-2_0_26-6_3_11-linux-2_6_tgz.php

When you unzip the tar file there are a number of files including a Kconfig and Makefile.  I used 'make && sudo make Kconfig.aic7xxx' to start the process of installing the driver.

I get the following error when I attempt to make the file: 
make: "no rule to make target '/aic7xxx_seq.h' needed by 'aic7xxx_core.o'

Running 'make && sudo make Makefile' comes up with the same error.

I have seen other answered questions say that the .h file probably does not exist in the directory where the makefile is being run.  This is not the case for my issue. I'm not sure if I am just not understanding how to install the driver or if there is an issue with the source code.

Any ideas on how I should proceed?

I will attach the code for the Konfig.aic7xxx file and Makefile below:

```html
#Konfig.aic7xxx: 

#
# AIC7XXX and AIC79XX 2.5.X Kernel configuration File.
# $Id: //depot/linux-aic79xx-2.5.0/drivers/scsi/aic7xxx/Kconfig.aic7xxx#11 $
#
config SCSI_AIC7XXX
 tristate "Adaptec AIC7xxx Fast -> U160 support (New Driver)"
 depends on (PCI || EISA) && SCSI
 ---help---
 This driver supports all of Adaptec's Fast through Ultra 160 PCI
 based SCSI controllers as well as the aic7770 based EISA and VLB
 SCSI controllers (the 274x and 284x series).  For AAA and ARO based
 configurations, only SCSI functionality is provided.

 To compile this driver as a module, choose M here: the
 module will be called aic7xxx.

config AIC7XXX_CMDS_PER_DEVICE
 int "Maximum number of TCQ commands per device"
 depends on SCSI_AIC7XXX
 default "32"
 ---help---
 Specify the number of commands you would like to allocate per SCSI
 device when Tagged Command Queueing (TCQ) is enabled on that device.

 This is an upper bound value for the number of tagged transactions
 to be used for any device.  The aic7xxx driver will automatically
 vary this number based on device behavior.  For devices with a
 fixed maximum, the driver will eventually lock to this maximum
 and display a console message inidicating this value.

 Due to resource allocation issues in the Linux SCSI mid-layer, using
 a high number of commands per device may result in memory allocation
 failures when many devices are attached to the system.  For this reason,
 the default is set to 32.  Higher values may result in higer performance
 on some devices.  The upper bound is 253.  0 disables tagged queueing.

 Per device tag depth can be controlled via the kernel command line
 "tag_info" option.  See drivers/scsi/aic7xxx/README.aic7xxx
 for details.

config AIC7XXX_RESET_DELAY_MS
 int "Initial bus reset delay in milli-seconds"
 depends on SCSI_AIC7XXX
 default "15000"
 ---help---
 The number of milliseconds to delay after an initial bus reset.
 The bus settle delay following all error recovery actions is
 dictated by the SCSI layer and is not affected by this value.

 Default: 15000 (15 seconds)

config AIC7XXX_PROBE_EISA_VL
 bool "Probe for EISA and VL AIC7XXX Adapters"
 depends on SCSI_AIC7XXX && EISA
 help
 Probe for EISA and VLB Aic7xxx controllers.  In many newer systems,
 the invasive probes necessary to detect these controllers can cause
 other devices to fail.  For this reason, the non-PCI probe code is
 disabled by default.  The current value of this option can be "toggled"
 via the no_probe kernel command line option.

config AIC7XXX_BUILD_FIRMWARE
 bool "Build Adapter Firmware with Kernel Build"
 depends on SCSI_AIC7XXX && !PREVENT_FIRMWARE_BUILD
 help
 This option should only be enabled if you are modifying the firmware
 source to the aic7xxx driver and wish to have the generated firmware
 include files updated during a normal kernel build.  The assembler
 for the firmware requires lex and yacc or their equivalents, as well
 as the db v1 library.  You may have to install additional packages
 or modify the assembler Makefile or the files it includes if your
 build environment is different than that of the author.

config AIC7XXX_DEBUG_ENABLE
 bool "Compile in Debugging Code"
 depends on SCSI_AIC7XXX
 default y
 help
 Compile in aic7xxx debugging code that can be useful in diagnosing
 driver errors.

config AIC7XXX_DEBUG_MASK
        int "Debug code enable mask (2047 for all debugging)"
        depends on SCSI_AIC7XXX
        default "0"
        help
 Bit mask of debug options that is only valid if the
 CONFIG_AIC7XXX_DEBUG_ENBLE option is enabled.  The bits in this mask
 are defined in the drivers/scsi/aic7xxx/aic7xxx.h - search for the
 variable ahc_debug in that file to find them.

config AIC7XXX_REG_PRETTY_PRINT
        bool "Decode registers during diagnostics"
        depends on SCSI_AIC7XXX
 default y
        help
 Compile in register value tables for the output of expanded register
 contents in diagnostics.  This make it much easier to understand debug
 output without having to refer to a data book and/or the aic7xxx.reg
 file.
```

```html
#Makefile:

#//depot/linux-aic79xx-2.5.0/drivers/scsi/aic7xxx/Makefile#10 - edit change 4216 (text+ko)
#
# Makefile for the Linux aic7xxx SCSI driver.
#
# $Id: //depot/linux-aic79xx-2.5.0/drivers/scsi/aic7xxx/Makefile#10 $
#

# Let kbuild descend into aicasm when cleaning
subdir-    += aicasm

obj-$(CONFIG_SCSI_AIC7XXX) += aic7xxx.o
obj-$(CONFIG_SCSI_AIC79XX) += aic79xx.o

# Core Fast -> U160 files
aic7xxx-y     += aic7xxx_core.o \
         aic7xxx_93cx6.o
aic7xxx-$(CONFIG_EISA)    += aic7770.o
aic7xxx-$(CONFIG_PCI)    += aic7xxx_pci.o
aic7xxx-$(CONFIG_AIC7XXX_REG_PRETTY_PRINT) += aic7xxx_reg_print.o

# Platform Specific Fast -> U160 Files
aic7xxx-y     += aic7xxx_osm.o \
         aic7xxx_proc.o
aic7xxx-$(CONFIG_EISA)    += aic7770_osm.o
aic7xxx-$(CONFIG_PCI)    += aic7xxx_osm_pci.o

# Core U320 files
aic79xx-y     += aic79xx_core.o \
         aic79xx_pci.o
aic79xx-$(CONFIG_AIC79XX_REG_PRETTY_PRINT) += aic79xx_reg_print.o

# Platform Specific U320 Files
aic79xx-y     += aic79xx_osm.o \
         aic79xx_proc.o \
         aic79xx_osm_pci.o

EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Idrivers/scsi
ifdef WARNINGS_BECOME_ERRORS
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Werror
endif
#EXTRA_CFLAGS += -g

# Files generated that shall be removed upon make clean
clean-files := aic7xxx_seq.h aic7xxx_reg.h aic7xxx_reg_print.c
clean-files += aic79xx_seq.h aic79xx_reg.h aic79xx_reg_print.c

# Dependencies for generated files need to be listed explicitly

$(obj)/aic7xxx_core.o: $(obj)/aic7xxx_seq.h
$(obj)/aic79xx_core.o: $(obj)/aic79xx_seq.h
$(obj)/aic79xx_reg_print.c: $(src)/aic79xx_reg_print.c_shipped
$(obj)/aic7xxx_reg_print.c: $(src)/aic7xxx_reg_print.c_shipped

$(addprefix $(obj)/,$(aic7xxx-y)): $(obj)/aic7xxx_reg.h
$(addprefix $(obj)/,$(aic79xx-y)): $(obj)/aic79xx_reg.h

aic7xxx-gen-$(CONFIG_AIC7XXX_BUILD_FIRMWARE) := $(obj)/aic7xxx_seq.h \
         $(obj)/aic7xxx_reg.h
aic7xxx-gen-$(CONFIG_AIC7XXX_REG_PRETTY_PRINT) += $(obj)/aic7xxx_reg_print.c

aicasm-7xxx-opts-$(CONFIG_AIC7XXX_REG_PRETTY_PRINT) := \
 -p $(obj)/aic7xxx_reg_print.c -i aic7xxx_osm.h

ifeq ($(CONFIG_AIC7XXX_BUILD_FIRMWARE),y)
# Create a dependency chain in generated files
# to avoid concurrent invocations of the single
# rule that builds them all.
aic7xxx_seq.h: aic7xxx_reg.h
ifeq ($(CONFIG_AIC7XXX_REG_PRETTY_PRINT),y)
aic7xxx_reg.h: aic7xxx_reg_print.c
endif
$(aic7xxx-gen-y): $(src)/aic7xxx.seq $(src)/aic7xxx.reg $(obj)/aicasm/aicasm
 $(obj)/aicasm/aicasm -I$(src) -r $(obj)/aic7xxx_reg.h \
         $(aicasm-7xxx-opts-y) -o $(obj)/aic7xxx_seq.h \
         $(src)/aic7xxx.seq
endif

aic79xx-gen-$(CONFIG_AIC79XX_BUILD_FIRMWARE) := $(obj)/aic79xx_seq.h \
         $(obj)/aic79xx_reg.h
aic79xx-gen-$(CONFIG_AIC79XX_REG_PRETTY_PRINT) += $(obj)/aic79xx_reg_print.c

aicasm-79xx-opts-$(CONFIG_AIC79XX_REG_PRETTY_PRINT) := \
 -p $(obj)/aic79xx_reg_print.c -i aic79xx_osm.h

ifeq ($(CONFIG_AIC79XX_BUILD_FIRMWARE),y)
# Create a dependency chain in generated files
# to avoid concurrent invocations of the single
# rule that builds them all.
aic79xx_seq.h: aic79xx_reg.h
ifeq ($(CONFIG_AIC79XX_REG_PRETTY_PRINT),y)
aic79xx_reg.h: aic79xx_reg_print.c
endif
$(aic79xx-gen-y): $(src)/aic79xx.seq $(src)/aic79xx.reg $(obj)/aicasm/aicasm
 $(obj)/aicasm/aicasm -I$(src) -r $(obj)/aic79xx_reg.h \
         $(aicasm-79xx-opts-y) -o $(obj)/aic79xx_seq.h \
         $(src)/aic79xx.seq
endif

$(obj)/aicasm/aicasm: $(src)/aicasm/*.[chyl]
 $(MAKE) -C $(src)/aicasm
```

Thanks in advance for any help.  I am new to programming and code in general so apologies in advance for any ignorance on my part.

Comment: That driver is from 2007. I think it's unlikely that it will work without substantial modifications on current kernels.

Comment: The leading slash looks like you somehow failed to populate `obj`. Try `make obj=.` or perhaps you can figure out a better directory to put there. Or just run `configure` again, this time with correct input parameters?

Comment: `sudo make Makefile` looks horribly wrong, do the instructions tell you to do that? If not, what do you hope this would do?

Comment: tripleee: Frankly I just ran the sudo make Makefile to see what would happen.  The documentation for installing the driver has absolutely no guidance as to how to make the package run.

Comment: janneb: that was one of my major concerns as well.  This driver was built for the 2.6 kernal and I am running on version 5.0.  For some extra background, I am a digital archivist and I am trying to access and create derivatives on DDS 2.0 tapes.  Buying this card was an attempt to use the drive the tapes were created on to access and image the files contained on them.

Comment: AIC_7xxx is in the kernel source.  You probably just need to load the module.  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/drivers/scsi/aic7xxxhttps://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/drivers/scsi/aic7xxx

Comment: What @stark said ... `linux-source-5.3.0# grep -ril 2940au .
./linux-source-5.3.0/Documentation/scsi/aic7xxx.txt
./linux-source-5.3.0/drivers/scsi/aic7xxx/aic7xxx_pci.c
./linux-source-5.3.0/drivers/scsi/aic7xxx/aic7xxx.h
./linux-source-5.3.0/drivers/scsi/aic7xxx/aic7xxx_pci.h
./linux-source-5.3.0/drivers/scsi/aic7xxx/aic7xxx_osm_pci.c`

Comment: The question, to me, at least, is whether the thing you bought is a) still working and b) if it's compatible with your other hardware.  If it doesn't feature in `dmesg` output and the module doesn't get loaded automatically there's probably something wrong on a hardware level ...

Comment: Thank you all for the help.  This card actually killed my motherboard overnight so I am dealing with a whole slew of new problems.  If and when I get the system back up and running I will test out some of these other solutions.